# What is the greatest number of field goals in an NFL game without any other scoring?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

On 2022-10-06, the [Colts defeated the Broncos 12-9](https://www.nfl.com/games/colts-at-broncos-2022-reg-5) with all the scoring being via 7 field goals. Is this the greatest number of field goals in an NFL game without there being any other form of scoring?

Comment: In 2007 there was a Colts-Ravens playoff game with 15-6 score. That's also 7 FGs: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.espn.com/nfl/game/_/gameId/270113033&ved=2ahUKEwie-NTQ09H6AhXoh4sKHZDMDpMQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3aQoWFllaNSmYRKskHtg5z